# Empty options in select element on Android 5.1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm try to using default template for select list on ionic app

```
<div class="list"> 
 <div class="item item-input item-select"> 
  <div class="input-label"> Lightsaber </div> 
  <select> 
   <option>Blue</option> 
   <option selected>Green</option> 
   <option>Red</option> 
  </select> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

for testing on my tablet with Android 5.1
But in conclusion I see only empty options in select. See  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkiI0.jpg)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
                Lightsaber
            </div>
            <select ng-model="inputTxt.color">
                <option value="" selected>--select--</option>
                <option value="color" selected>Blue</option>
                <option value="color">Green</option>
                <option value="color">Red</option>
            </select>
</label>
```

Comment: No, don't help for me